# Перемножить значения в ячейках таблицы

Tags: javascript

Добрый вечер всем.Подскажите как правильно сделать переумножение значений в ячейках.в ячейкх таблицы находятся текстовые поля,значения которых как раз надо переумножить  по нажатию на кнопку 'Посчитать стоимость'.Таблица формируется вот таки образом:

```
 var outputData = document.getElementById("outputData");
        var total = outputData.getElementsByTagName("TH");
        var regExp = new RegExp(/([VPFERUL]+)\s\(x(\d+)\)/g);

        var table = "<table class = 'calculator'>";
            table += "<tr><th></th><th>Цена(кр)</th><th>Кол-во</th><th>Сумма</th></tr>";

        for(var i=0;i<total.length;i++){
            var result = total[i].firstChild.nodeValue.match(regExp);

            table += "<tr>";
            table += "<td width = '40px' class="+RegExp.$1+"><b>"+RegExp.$1+"</b></td>";
            table += "<td width = '110px'><input type = 'text' size= '6' maxlength = '6'></td>";
            table += "<td width = '110px'><input type = 'text' size = '6' value = "+RegExp.$2+"></td>";
            table += "<td></td></tr>";
        }

        table += "<tr><td colspan = '4'><input type = 'button' id = 'count' value = 'Посчитать стоимость'></td></tr>"
        table += "</table>";
        calculator.innerHTML = table;
```

Comment: таблица формируется дебильным образом

Comment: ну подскажите тогда как лучше

Comment: через document.createElement конечно же.

Comment: И в чем будет разница?

Comment: @Женька Сидоров в том, что вы сможете ссылки на ячейки хранить в массиве.